# launch external activity w/o it appearing in the back stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack

I need to launch an external `activity` (which isn't mine) for a split second, and then I have a `service` that launches my previous `activity` for the user to see.

This works great, but the problem is when the user then presses the back key, he gets to that external `activity`.

I have two different `activity` launches here, one for the external `activity`, and one for my `activity` to return to (in which I need to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` because I'm launching it from a `service`).

For these two launches I've tried any combination of:
`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`.

Nothing helps, I keep seeing the external `activity` after pressing back.

I've seen some similar questions here, but they all have the middle activity in their own app, so they can call finish on it, or set `noHistory="true"` in the manifest.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Seems like the issue is that I re-launch my previous activity from a service, which means I need to give it FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, from the documentation of [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes):

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK Start the activity in a new task. If a task is
>   already running for the activity you are now starting, that task is
>   brought to the foreground with its last state restored and the
>   activity receives the new intent in onNewIntent(). **This produces the
>   same behavior as the "singleTask" launchMode value**, discussed in the
>   previous section.

And from the singleTask paragraph:

> "singleTask" The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the root of the new task
>   ...
>   Note: Although the activity starts in a
>   new task, **the Back button still returns the user to the previous
>   activity**.

So I need a flag that overrides this behavior somehow...